# odoo report print object value

Tags: odoo, qweb

I am new to odoo and learning a bit related to reporting. i was looking around stock picking report. i noticed that it has an object called "docs" and the values are stored inside this object. 
as i am from PHP background there are possibilities to print the object received for debugging purpose as follows:

```
<?php print_r("object"); ?>
```

So i tried to print the same thing in odoo using QWeb template using below codes :

```
1. <t t-esc="docs" />
2. <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
      <t t-esc="o" />
3. <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
      <t t-esc="o_all" />
4. <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
      <t t-esc="o_value" />
5. <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
      <t t-esc="o_all" />
```

But i was unable to print the whole object, i only get stock.picking(1,)
Can someone help me how can i see the whole object with keys and values in qweb template. Moreover can someone guide me where this object "docs" is defined.

I will really appreciate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stock.picking(1,)` is a single object so it doesn't have key and values which dictionaries have. so i guess what you want to see are the attributes the object has like the id, name and so on

you can do that by using the `dir` function, that's the equivalent of `print_r` on an object in php (not really),

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
    <t t-esc="dir(o)" />
```

That will print out all the attribute that the object has, if you want to see a specific attribute like the id you can do this

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
    <t t-esc="o.id" />
```

`dir` gives a lot more information, but you can still get the same behaviour as php's `print_r` with some little modifications. for example

```
class Example:
    whatever = 'whatever attribute'
    something = 'something attribute'

ex = Example()

print({attribute: getattr(ex, attribute) for attribute in dir(ex) if not attribute.startswith('__')})
```

Here i used a dictionary comprehension to loop through all the attributes of the object returned by `dir` before then i used an if statement to  strip out all the extra information about the object that dir gives us which usually start with two underscores (`__`).

Hence the output is a dictionary with the object attributes as keys and the values are the contents of those attributes

```
{'whatever': 'whatever attribute', 'something': 'something attribute'}
```

**Untested by me. but this should work in QWeb also**

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
    <t t-esc="{attribute: getattr(o, attribute) for attribute in dir(o) if not attribute.startswith('__')}" />
```

Comment: Doing `t-esc="dir(product)"` gives me an error: `"'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating dir(product)`

Comment: What is `product` exactly? how are you getting `product` compared to the original question that was asked?

Comment: Pretty much the same way. `t-esc="product"` gives `product.template(31,)`. However using `dir()` will result in error mentioned above.

Comment: `t-esc="dir(o)"`? also what is the error you're getting....you might need to ask a new question and give more details

Comment: The error I'm getting is written in my first comment. The `product` object is not important. I'm getting same error without any object: `<t t-esc="dir()"/>`, placing that in any template.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Diderh answer, see how to display each attributes of an object with their related values:

```
<table>
    <t t-foreach="product._fields" t-as="field">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <t t-esc="field" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <t t-esc="product[field]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </t>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime we are a little lost how to print the fields for an particular object in website Odoo v12, you can use a simple code to show wholes fields. Here how i did it for Object Forum:

```
<t t-foreach="forums.sorted(reverse=True)" t-as="forum">
   <t t-esc="forum._fields" />
</t>
```